# Combining 2 IQueryable results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I found some questions that looked similar, but not exactly the same so I'll go for it.

I'm using EF to retrieve 2 tables. These tables/entities have no real "is a" relationship. They just happen to have a couple of common fields which I want to expose in a list containing the first N entries of a combination between the two tables. Each row has to have some way of identifying which type it is and which instance it points to.

I have solved the problem, but I guess I was wondering if there was a better way. My solution was to create a ViewModel class:

```
intenal class EntityAEntityBCombination
{
    public int? EntityAID { get; set; }
    public int? EntityBID { get; set; }
    public string CommonProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I did this:

```
var results = (
    from a in EntityAList select new EntityAEntityBCombination
        { EntityAID = a.Id, EntityBID = null, CommonProperty = a.CommonProperty }
    ).Concat(
    from b in EntityBList select new EntityAEntityBCombination
        { EntityAID = null, EntitiyBID = b.Id, CommonProperty = b.CommonProperty }
    ).Fetch(N)
```

It works, but seems dirty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can `EntityA` and `EntityB` not use the same interface and then you return a `List<IEntity>` which contains them both? It seems more OOP to me than returning anonymous types.

Comment: I think an interface is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this, perhaps it doesn't work straight out of the box, but it should give you an idea:

```
public class EntityA : IEntity
{}

public class EntityB : IEntity
{}

List<IEntity> results = 
(from a in EntityAList select a).Cast<IEntity>()
.Concat(
(from b in EntityBList select b).Cast<IEntity>()
)
.Fetch(N).ToList();

foreach (IEntity entity in results)
{
 if (entity is EntityA)
  // do something with entity A

 if (entity is EntityB)
  // do something with entity B
}
```

Comment: I think I might end up doing something like this.

Comment: Would there be any reason why you would not like to end up like this? I'm open to suggestions of improving the idea. :)

Comment: I was trying to keep my structures as simple as possible trying to teach myself EF, MVC, IoC etc. No other reason really...

Comment: You could go with a Base class which is inherited by both EntityA and EntityB if you feel better about that. Practically it comes down to the same thing. :) Just when you have two classes that have "some" things in common your "interface-alert" should start ringing. :) I think your EntityAEntityBCombination class is not much different from it.